# Paint not sticking to drywall

Tags: paint

In my new house, the paint will not stick to the wall. It will just start pealing like a piece of tape. How do I correctly paint so this doesn't happen?

[image]

Comment: The drywall already has a coat of paint on it.  You need a paint or primer that will stick to the existing paint.

Comment: Please describe the steps you have taken to prepare the wall. Are you certain the wall is drywall? What is it finished with? And what are we looking at in this picture?

Comment: If there is already paint I use a Tri sodium phosphate mixed with water, a sponge mop wipe the walls then a quick rinse and have not had this problem, is this in a kitchen?

Comment: This is in the bathroom, but it has happened in every painted room. We have scraped the paint to the drywall and tried again, but it still does. It happened with the original paint there when we bought the house.

Comment: Plus 1 for suggesting TSP.  Sometimes, in cold climates, when the house is being built in the winter, the workers will use heaters that may leave a residue on the walls and ceilings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My background is 21 years of managing a retail paint store.

You need to remove what you can remove of the de-laminating paint. Make sure the wall is free of dust and any kind of contamination. Rub the back of the peeling paint film and if it's dusty/chalky, this is your culprit.

Please use a primer of high quality. If water-based, use one that is 100% acrylic like Aqualock by Insl-X. Certain hard-to-paint surfaces like polished plaster can be primed with products like Zinsser BIN shellac-based primer or Insl-X's Stix.

Contaminations like moisture, dust/chalk, dirt, etc. can cause this kind of delamination.

Whatever the cause, find the source and eliminate before doing any more coating.

Comment: Hi, thanks. We scraped all the old paint off, then cleaned the wall and applied the paint. This happened with the original paint they had on the wall.  I'm guessing it needs better cleaning of getting the dust off and an actual primer. Not paint that includes the primer. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: Is there another primer you would recommend that lowes or home depot has? I'm guessing the dust and bare drywall is the issue. It looks like they never primed the walls.

Comment: Any 100% Acrylic primer will do. Zinsser Bullseye 1-2-3 is a good one.